# Using 2 or more Firebase Realtime DB inside a single Activity

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

As a Blaze plan users I can create multiple database instances so that default database not gonna stuck at 100k simultaneous connections. Thing is, I'm trying to call the data from both database, because some data are inside Database 1, and some other are in Database 2. So, in Kotlin, I've declared my Firebase Instances as follow;

```
val db: DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
```

Well the above line works for the default DB (Databse 1).
Usually if I wanna call the data from Database 2 for another Activity (not this one right now), I need to include the instance name which is the HTTPS link in the getInstance() method as follow;

```
val dataBase: DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://projectName.firebasio.com").reference
```

In this case, I've tried to use this 2 declaration and it seems to give me error.

Attach image:
[image: 2 DB Instance]

Logcat only states that it is E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main and occurs at the second instances decalration which is

```
 val dataBase: DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://projectName.firebasio.com").reference
```

Logcat:

> Caused by: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid
>   Firebase Database path: https//projectName.firebaseio.com. Firebase
>   Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzepf.zzqn(Unknown Source:52)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzepf.zzqo(Unknown Source:13)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzepd.zzqj(Unknown Source:131)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown
>   Source:45)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown
>   Source:14)
>           at paackageName.CountryList.(CountryList.kt:22)
>           at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1173)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2708)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Comment: Could you edit your question to be specific about the error?

Comment: @DougStevenson edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL in your second call to getInstance() is invalid.  It's missing a colon after "https".

Comment: OMG what a mess I am missing a colon unexpectedly  btw, it also solved the question of using 2 DBs of same project into same Activity/Fragment.

Comment: Please accept this answer as correct if it helped solve your problem.

Comment: Done. I thought Firebase still haven't got the features yet until I tried it myself...

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for this can be found here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/#support_multiple_environments_in_your_android_application

```
// Manually configure Firebase Options
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setApplicationId("1:27992087142:android:ce3b6448250083d1") // Required for Analytics.
        .setApiKey("AIzaSyADUe90ULnQDuGShD9W23RDP0xmeDc6Mvw") // Required for Auth.
        .setDatabaseUrl("https://myproject.firebaseio.com") // Required for RTDB.
        .build();
```

Comment: The OP is asking about multiple database shards within a single project, not multiple databases split between different projects.