# Firebase : How to log the full reference on read/write error

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to connect to another database on an Android App, and can't seem to see if I've successfully init the secondary database.

How I'm instantiating the second one.

```
public void initFirebase() {
    //init the default db;
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);

    //init the second db;
    FirebaseOptions.Builder builder = new FirebaseOptions.Builder();
    builder.setApplicationId("id");
    builder.setApiKey("key");
    builder.setDatabaseUrl("https://second-db.firebaseio.com");

    try {
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, builder.build(), "second-db");
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then I try to read something here.

```
public static DatabaseReference getSecondDbRef(String child) {
    FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.getInstance("second-db");
    return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(app).getReference(child);
}
```

Then this fails with some: `Listen at /child/child/child/teams` failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied, though I've allowed access at this location and can confirm with the rules simulator that this node can be read.

Is there a way to have this log: `Listen to second-db/child/child/child/teams failed ...`, notice the prefix `second-db`.

Comment: i think you have to go this url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37874920/can-multiple-android-application-access-same-firebase-database

Comment: @Rohit that question is not related to what I'm asking. I want to access two different databases from the same Android app, not the same database from two different Android apps.

Comment: Just add another Firebase Instance in the Activity. Then call the Value Event Listener for the child that related to the 2nd DB instance. Such as in here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50160542/using-2-or-more-firebase-realtime-db-inside-a-single-activity